# Postgis: optimal raster tile size for spatial join with census enumeration district polygons

Tags: join, polygon, postgis, raster

The question is about how to choose raster tile size when importing rasters of 30x30m spatial resolution into a Postgis database in order to optimize a spatial join with a complex polygons.

**i.e., in raster2pgsql, how do you chose the "-t" switch to optimize the spatial join query?**

The raster data indicates slope derived from SRTM data at 30m resolution.
The polygons represent the enumeration districts (setor censitário) of the Brasilian Census. An enumeration district corresponds to the area covering 300 households (~ 1/4 of a US census track) and in urban areas can range from 1 to 8 city blocks).

I'm trying to obtain the average terrain slope for each enumeration district, using the following query:

```
-- importing
shp2pgsql -c -s 4674:4326 -I -W LATIN1 enum_districs_2010  public.enum_districs_2010 | psql -d r342471958
raster2pgsql -c -s 4326 -I -t 100x100 *.tif  public.slope | psql -d r342471958

-- average slop per enum distric
select sv.cd_geocodi, SUM(sv.val * ST_Area(sv.geom)) / ST_Area(ST_Union(sv.geom)) As avgsqm
  from (
     select set.cd_geocodi, (ST_Intersection(slo.rast,1, set.geom)).*
  from enum_districs_2010 set
     inner join slopes slo on ST_Intersects(slo.rast, 1, set.geom)
  ) sv 
group by sv.cd_geocodi
```

is there some rule of thumb on choosing tile size (-t)?

Comment: I think it is an interesting question. How is performance? Worse than you expect? Have you done any experiments on different sizes? My general experience with spatial queries is that you have to test with your own data as the query optimizer can't help very much, as it is concerned with the cost of fetching from disk and index usage, not on the relative performance of this polygon/raster intersections.

Comment: So far I tryed merging the enumeration districts of hole São Paulo Metropolitan (8.5k km2, about the size of Jamaica) against the 1x1 degree tiles of the raster data that overlaps it. It runs for a few hours and then crashes my machine ((Unbantu 12.04 LTS, Memory:7.8gb). I have no Idea how the index works and if it is being "spatially smart", doing the spatial comparisons hierarchically, etc. I'll now try looping over a moving bounding box, and doing the intersections within each box.  Also, tks for the edits

Comment: Sao Paulo Metropolitan district, the size of Jamaica, lol. OK, what happens when you put explain in front of your query?

Comment: EXPLAINs: "GroupAggregate (cost=681295134.45..735325929.45 rows=16622486000 width=50) ..." So I don´t know what the 735 million cost means in terms of time. Should I play around with "-t" when importing the raster to see if I can lower this cost? Is this the cost I should be worried about anyway?

Comment: I don't understand why your spatial indexes are not being used. That basically means no indexes, and 16622486000 rows being fetched. And then on top, you are doing aggregate functions.

Comment: OK, I think your problem might be the inner join slopes slo on ST_Intersects(slo.rast, 1, set.geom). Try where st_intersects(slo.rast, 1, set.geom) instead.

Comment: Did that, changing the inner query to: select ...   from teste_shape_setores set, teste_slope_rmtodas slo    where st_intersects(slo.ras,1,set.geom)  .  But the estimated cost is not changing.

Comment: I also tryed running what is suggested in the second post of this tread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/postgis-users/$20st_clip$20mean$20raster$20value/postgis-users/gGRYcMweTNM/G6ugEbTUaCcJ  (the first suggested code). But I'm not being able to debug it.

Comment: I have added an answer, for formatting reasons, as the comments are getting a bit long here. My suggestion for writing the join is similar to what is suggested in that thread. Suggest you try a smaller raster tile size?

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this? A very interesting question, I thought.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the delay. I managed to do it but had to break it into smaller tasks and do a loop.  I'll post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Going back to spatial indexes, I think they are being used, but they don´t make the problem that much smaller. Joining the São Paulo Metro area Shapefile (68296 polygons) with the 30x30m tile raster has (1069200 lines) PostGIS makes 2.3e+10 (23148534000) comparisons. The brute force approach, tying everything against everything, would be of 7.3e+10 (73022087168)  comparisons.

Comment: Same thing if I use a larger tile size (100x100, table with 76788 lines) against the same polygons: 1.6e+9 comparisons are made. Brute force would be 5.2e+9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the cleanest way of writing a spatial join for vector/raster intersection.

```sql
select sv.cd_geocodi, avg(sv.val) As avgsqm
    from (
       select set.cd_geocodi, (ST_Intersection(slo.rast, 1, distr.geom)).*
    from enum_districs_2010 distr, slopes slo 
       where ST_Intersects(slo.rast, 1, distr.geom)
  ) sv 
group by sv.cd_geocodi
```

Also I think you should be able to use the avg function, as you are already grouping by census district.
The question as to the optimal tile for a raster/vector intersection is a good one and one for which it is difficult to give a clear rule of thumb. Generally, as you actually have to open the rasters to get at their pixel values, you are going to want to choose rasters that are similar in size (possibly a little bigger) then your vector parcels, this way, in the worst case, you are only going to have to open 4 rasters for each vector polygon with which you are intersecting. Ultimately, the optimal ratio of raster to vector size is a complex statistical problem, but anecdotally (from newsgroup posts), and intuitively, smaller raster sizes would be expected to perform better than bigger ones. I would suggest that you try reducing your raster tiles sizes a little bit.

The output of explain can be hard to understand with spatial data, as the cost is essentially, a measure of the cost of pulling the data from disk, and does not consider the cost of the underlying spatial operations such as intersects and intersection. Your explain output suggests that the spatial index is not being used, possibly another reason to try with smaller tiles sizes. Also, add a primary key to enum_districts, if you haven't already, run analyze to update the statistics, and try explain again. Sometimes which complex spatial queries, explain might not change much, so I would still suggest that you try running the query and see if it gets any faster.

Comment: I've tried a ton of sizes for similar analysis on 1 square mile areas and "auto", which is pretty small keeps winning. That being said it's slow as hell when I need to do ~1000 areas. If I could figure out how to store the raster as integers instead of double precision, I'm betting that would help....

Comment: @ideamotor. That sounds like a decent question? Sadly, the OP never posted his solution to this one, although I think the consensus is for smaller raster sizes, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think the best thing you can do to improve the speed is to use the `ST_SummaryStats` function.

In my case:

```
select (ST_SummaryStats(ST_UNION(rasters.rast))).mean, parcels.gid
from (select gid, "geomLocal" as geom from surfaceparcel where lnd_ac > 200) as parcels, rasters.shadow_48135 as rasters
where ST_Intersects(rasters.rast, geom)
group by parcels.gid
order by parcels.gid
```

3-4 seconds...

---

OLD POST:

This is more of further discussion. So as previously mentioned "auto" which is small was the best on my twenty or so tests - note I'm joining to 1-mile areas. In fact I was getting errors on some smaller sizes so this seems wise. Now as far as other ways to speed this up, I tried several various things.

First of all make sure your database is configured properly. This isn't quite comprehensive but it's good: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/dataadmin/pgDBAdmin/tuning.html.

Secondly, I tried making the rasters smaller. You may want to try `python` but I default to `R`. You'll need to change the EPSG code and the filenames.

```r
system('raster2pgsql -I -C -M -t "auto" -s 3663 slope.tif rasters.slopeBig | psql -d postgres')
library(raster)
changeRasterValue <- function(r,bs,i,out) {
  oldVal <- getValues(r,row=bs$row[i],nrows=bs$nrows[i])
  newVal <- as.integer(round(oldVal*1000))
  writeValues(out,newVal,bs$row[i])
  print(sprintf("layer %s complete",i))}
r  <- raster("slope.tif")
bs <- blockSize(out)
out <- writeStart(out,filename='slope1000int.tif',overwrite=TRUE)
sapply(1:bs$n, function(x) changeRasterValue(r,bs,x,out))
out <- writeStop(out)
print(data.frame("raster" = c("oldRaster","newRaster")
  ,"means" = c(cellStats(r,mean),cellStats(out,mean))
  ,"maxs" = c(cellStats(r,max),cellStats(out,max))))
system("gdal_translate -ot Int16 slope1000int.tif slopeSmall.tif")
system('raster2pgsql -I -C -M -t "auto" -s 3663 slopeSmall.tif rasters.slopetestSmall | psql -d postgres')
```

There I took the original raster values and multiplied by 1000 so when I converted to Int16 using `gdal_translate` it would still contain the data with some precision.

I wanted to go ahead and share that code but the fact is that is didn't help despite halving the raster file size. Any ideas? One item that did help in my case was fixing the data I was joining to. I used `T_MakeValid((ST_Dump(geom)).geom)` to convert my multipolygons to polygons and made sure to include indexes on the geom and the gid.

So the next idea was to just go ahead and parallelize the queries. This is some nontrivial `R` code and you'll need to change the table you are joining to, the number of cores, database authentication and schemas.

```r
# SETUP
library(doMC)
library(foreach)
coresUsed <- 8
registerDoMC(cores=coresUsed)
library(RPostgreSQL)
user_db <- "postgres"
pass_db <- readLines("/home/ideamotor/Desktop/pw")
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="postgres", user=user_db,
                 password=pass_db,host="localhost",port="5432")
# SPLIT
query <- "SELECT gid from surfaceparcel_fix"
gids <- data.frame(fetch(dbSendQuery(con,statement = paste(query)),n=-1))
gids <- gids[order(gids),]
firstgid <- gids[c(1)]
othergids <- gids[-c(1)]
chunk <- function(x, n) split(x, sort(rank(as.numeric(x)) %% n+1))
chunks <- chunk(othergids,coresUsed)
queries <- vector()
for (i in 1:coresUsed) {
  queries[i] <- 
  sprintf("INSERT INTO slopesSmall (vectorGID, avgslope) (
SELECT vectorGID, round(avg(val))/1000.0 As avgslope
FROM(
  SELECT vectors.gid as vectorGID, round(((ST_Intersection(rasters.rast,1, vectors.geom)).val)::numeric) as val
  FROM surfaceparcel_fix as vectors, rasters.slopetestSmall as rasters 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rasters.rast, 1, vectors.geom)
  AND vectors.gid >= %s and vectors.gid <= %s
    ) as t1
group by vectorGID);",min(chunks[[i]]),max(chunks[[i]]))
}

# CREATE TABLE TO INSERT INTO
query2 <- sprintf("CREATE TABLE slopesSmall as
    SELECT vectorGID, round(avg(val))/1000.0 As avgslope
    FROM(
      SELECT vectors.gid as vectorGID, round(((ST_Intersection(rasters.rast,1, vectors.geom)).val)::numeric) as val
      FROM surfaceparcel_fix as vectors, rasters.slopetestSmall as rasters 
        WHERE ST_Intersects(rasters.rast, 1, vectors.geom)
      AND vectors.gid = %s
        ) as t1
    group by vectorGID;",firstgid)
dbSendQuery(con,statement = paste(query2))
dbDisconnect(con)

# INSERT INTO TABLE
system.time(foreach(i=1:coresUsed,.packages=c("RPostgreSQL")) %dopar% {
  user_db <- "postgres"
  pass_db <- readLines("/home/ideamotor/Desktop/pw")
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="postgres", user=user_db,
                   password=pass_db,host="localhost",port="5432")
  query <- queries[i]
  dbSendQuery(con,statement = paste(query))
  dbDisconnect(con)
})
```

Running that for either file results in around the same time, around 100 seconds in my case, for 700 1-square mile regions. I did notice slightly more reasonable a values for edge cases with the Int16 results, which I'll have to dig into more.

So this is better than the 15 minutes I was looking at originally, but imagine doing this for the entire county for aspect, slope, and roughness while obtaining a histogram instead of an average value.... Any other ideas? One thought I have is reducing the extents (pre-clip) of the rasters that I join to but doesn't that defeat the point of a database?